# DAX Query to build current quarter numbers and same quarter last year’s numbers for snapshot data

Tags: powerbi, dax

I’m currently dealing with sales pipeline analysis where weekly snaps are taken for the data to see how has pipeline progressed.

Snap date is nothing but the date when weekly snap was taken.

I would like to fetch this quarter’s latest snap date’s number and also fetch data from snapdate around similar period for sa me quarter last year.

Currently the logic I have built helps me fetch data only from the recent snap date but not from any snap date from same quarter last year.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sameperiodlastyear-function-dax) function together with the snap date.

Answer (score 0):

There are some Time Intelligence Functions in DAX which could help you to do this task

```
DATESMTD
DATESQTD
DATESYTD
SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR
```

or

```
TOTALMTD
TOTALQTD
TOTALYTD
```

or combination some of them:

```
=CALCULATE([Lit] / 5.678,
          DATEADD(DATESQTD('Calendar'[DayDate]),
          -1,
          YEAR
                  )                                                   
         )
```

Example:

```
   =IF( COUNTROWS( VALUES( DimPeriod[Period]))=1, 
    IF( VALUES( DimPeriod[Period]) = "Current", [Sales], 
    IF( VALUES( DimPeriod[Period]) = "MTD", [Sales](DATESMTD(DimDate[Datekey])), 
    IF( VALUES( DimPeriod[Period]) = "QTD", [Sales](DATESQTD(DimDate[Datekey])), 
    IF( VALUES( DimPeriod[Period]) = "YTD", [Sales](DATESYTD(DimDate[Datekey])), 
    IF( VALUES( DimPeriod[Period]) = "LastYear", [Sales](DATEADD(DimDate[Datekey],-1,YEAR)), 
    IF( VALUES( DimPeriod[Period]) = "PriorYearMTD", [Sales](DATEADD(DATESMTD(DimDate[Datekey]),-1,YEAR)), 
    IF( VALUES( DimPeriod[Period]) = "PriorYearQTD", [Sales](DATEADD(DATESQTD(DimDate[Datekey]),-1,YEAR)), 
    IF( VALUES( DimPeriod[Period]) = "PriorYearYTD", [Sales](DATEADD(DATESYTD(DimDate[Datekey]),-1,YEAR)), 
    BLANK())))))))),[Sales])
```

Please see this article for help:
[Time Intelligence Functions in DAX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/04/12/time-intelligence-functions-in-dax/)